# How to create PHP function to render menu?

Tags: php

I do render menu in HTML like that

```
<div id="mybuttonscontainer">


    <ul>        


<li><a href="<?php echo get_link('option1'); ?>"> Option 1</a></li>         


<li><a href="<?php echo get_link('option2'); ?>">Option 2</a></li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

Now I want to put that code into function

```
render_menu('current_option');
```

Do I have to put the whole string into one **echo** statement?

Comment: Is the 'current_option' that is passed into your render_menu function one of the two options that is already in the list?

Comment: hayashi-kei, yes. Because selected option is rendered differently. My question is what perfect render_menu function should look like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can put it all in echo or just use it like that by wrapping it inside [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

```
<?php
function render_menu($what_menu)
{
    ob_start();
    ?>
<!-- put all your previous html and php code here -->
    <?php
    $data = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: why do you add the output buffering functions?

Comment: you might want to better control where the output take place. You know, do code processing above and put it's value somewhere below or in it's view.

Comment: Ah, ok then. I usually put of my logic before any output, so that's why it seemed to me a little weird.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your function like
`render_menu('current_option');` the **whole** string should be echoed inside the function, if
`echo render_menu('current_option');` then it **whole** string should be `return` by function